# How to create a complex SVG layer fill animation based on CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, svg, cashapelayer, caanimation, svgkit

As you can understand from the title of this question I am trying to achieve fill animation of CALayer(CAShapeLayer) of SVG file.

How complex should be animation you can see from the images I attached.
[image: P1. a few ms after animation start]
[image: P2. a few ms after P1]

I decided to start just with a circle and animate it to fill a layer below. Everything works pretty well.
[image]

So, I started building UIBezierPath or something like that but it looks like I am going the wrong direction.

I would really appreciate if you can just give me different ideas how to achieve it.
For SVG I use SVGKit. Maybe by using these set of classes, I can do something.

Thank you!

Comment: If you know how to use After Effects, you can use https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios.

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez I don't know how to use After Effects but I think it is not a problem. You mean create animation there and use it as a CAShapeLayer? I am not sure how to do it from the XML file. Anyway, thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Any update on this? I have a similar need and I'm looking for options. `CABasicAnimation` perhaps?